# Use the quadratic formula to find all degree solutions and θ if 0° ≤ θ < 360°

Tags: trigonometry

Use the quadratic formula to find all degree solutions and $\theta$ if 
$0° \le \theta < 360°$.

Use a calculator to approximate all answers to the nearest tenth of a degree. (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list. If there is no solution, enter NO SOLUTION.)

$$\cos^2 \theta + \cos \theta − 1 = 0$$

(a) all degree solutions (Let $k$ be any integer)

(b) $0° \le \theta < 360°$.

My work so far: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZhBs.jpg

Any help on how I should do this is greatly appreciated...

Comment: where did $x$ come from? $\theta = x$. Huh?

Comment: This fells like it is a test question entered from a cell phone.  If so, it is inappropriate to use this site to cheat on the test.  The instructions on the question tell you exactly what steps to do to solve this except that there will be 2 soluThey both come from the same solution to the quadratic equation. tions, one between 0 and 90, the other between 90 and 180 degrees.  Your calculator won't exhibit the second of these automatically.

Comment: It's not a test question, its online homework from webassign.com :). The class has been over since last saturday, but the online homework deadline is tonight at midnight. http://i.imgur.com/8FF2civ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that $$\cos \theta = \frac{-1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} \vee \cos \theta = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$$.

Only the latter one gives two solutions: $$\theta = 51.8^\circ \vee \theta = 360^\circ - 51.8^\circ = 308.2^\circ$$

Comment: what does the 'v' stand for?

Comment: In mathematics and logic, the v stands for 'or', so theta is 128.2 degrees or theta is 231.8 degrees.

Comment: I don't understand how you got 128.2 degrees though?

Comment: Taking cos^(-1) or arccos on the calculator.

Comment: When I do arccos(-1+root5)/2) on the calculator I get 51.83, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No, I was doing something wrong.